# Overloaded ToString does not appear in intellisense

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I was folowing the tutorial at [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6Zb0nD7PHA&list=PLdbkZkVDyKZVvizO94tJNmTfRzXWGDFZ3). At 8:04 instructor attached the local method to overloaded ToString, when I try to do same I don't see the overloaded method in intellisense.

[image]

```
 public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }

        public string ToString(PersonFormat format)
        {
           return format(this);
        }
```

I tried adding the keyword override too it does not work.Looks like I am missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because var is hiding the actual type of the `person` which is object when accessed through `PersonListBox.Items`. The below works:

```
foreach(Person person in PersonListBox.Items)
{


}
```

While :

```
foreach(var person in PersonListBox.Items)
{
    // person is object. It doesn't have the method you want to call. 
    // it even doesn't have FirstName or LastName
    // try person. and you can clearly see it only has the common
    // object methods.
}
```

Hint: you can also use `foreach(var p in PersonListBox.Items.OfType<Person>())`

Comment: @ user3185569: Accepted ! Thanks a lot !